# Compilation Failure - Library/Directory does not exist

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am modifying a Java project, and have included some libraries in the "main" Java programs that are used in the test Java files.  After I include these libraries, the project won't compile.  When these libraries are included in just the test Java files, everything compiles fine. I looked in the pom.xml and settings.xml files for clues, but nothing stood out.

Here is the error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project translator-ws: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>   [ERROR] ~/dv-6.4.0-src/teiid-parent-8.12.11.6_4-redhat-64-12/connectors/translator-ws/src/main/java/org/teiid/translator/ws/WSExecutionFactory.java:[56,17] package org.junit does not exist
>   [ERROR] ~/dv-6.4.0-src/teiid-parent-8.12.11.6_4-redhat-64-12/connectors/translator-ws/src/main/java/org/teiid/translator/ws/WSExecutionFactory.java:[57,19] package org.mockito does not exist
>   [ERROR] ~/dv-6.4.0-src/teiid-parent-8.12.11.6_4-redhat-64-12/connectors/translator-ws/src/main/java/org/teiid/translator/ws/WSExecutionFactory.java:[58,21] package org.teiid.cdk does not exist

The test Java files are in ~/dv-6.4.0-src/teiid-parent-8.12.11.6_4-redhat-64-12/connectors/translator-ws/src/test/java/org/teiid/translator/ws/*.java

Obviously, the test Java files can "see" those libraries, but the main Java files cannot.

I can include the pom.xml file if anybody wants to look at it.

Comment: *and have included some libraries in the "main" Java programs that are used in the test Java files*... if you do so, you need to ensure the scope of the dependencies for that code is `compile` as default. For that, you can simply remove `<scope>test</scope>` from your pom.xml. But the bigger question to ask yourself is why do you want to make use of test dependency in main source.

Comment: Thank you, nullpointer.  The scope in pom.xml is **provided** rather than **test**.  I changed the scope to **compile** and got the same errors.  I will attach the pom.xml file below.

Comment: `<groupId>org.jboss.teiid.connectors</groupId>
    <name>Web service Translator</name>
    <description>This translator provides access to Web Services.</description>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.teiid</groupId>
            <artifactId>teiid-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.teiid</groupId>
            <artifactId>teiid-common-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>`

Comment: That is just a snippet.

Comment: I want to make use of the test dependency in the main source because I am replicating a portion of one of the test functions in the main program.